# Python: forcing precision on a floating point number in json?

Tags: python, json

**(update)**

Here's the actual problem I'm seeing.  Note that round() doesn't seem to be doing the trick.

Here's my code:

```
t0=time.time()
# stuff
t1=time.time()
perfdat={'et1' : round(t1-t0,6), 'et2': '%.6f'%(t1-t0)}
```

And the dict and json output, respectively:

```
{'et2': '0.010214', 'et1': 0.010214000000000001}

{"et2":"0.010214","et1":0.010214000000000001}
```

**(end update)**

I've got a floating point value that has a lot of extra digits of precision that I don't need.  Is there a way to truncate those digits when formatting a json string?

I can get the truncation I need if I format the value as a string, but I would like to transmit the value as a (truncated) number.

```
import json
v=2.030000002

json.dumps({'x':v})     # would like to just have 2.030
'{"x": 2.030000002}'

s= '%.3f' % (v)         # like this, but not as a string
json.dumps({'x' : s})
'{"x": "2.030"}'
```

Comment: Do you require the trailing 0?

Comment: I can't imagine why the trailing zero would matter. Virtually every JSON library decodes it to a floating-point value anyway, which loses that information.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I agree, but on the other hand I also can't imagine a 100k user being unable to find the `round()` function on google or elsewhere on SO, because it this topic has been asked about before

Comment: The `json.JSONEncoder` class, the type of default "extensible" JSON encoder used by the `json` module, can only be extended to handle types other than those it handles itself as shown in this [conversion table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#py-to-json-table). Because `float` is one of the types it does know how to handle, changing how that is done can't be accomplished via subclassing. However, since Python is open-source, you're free to get a copy of it and provide your own implementation that does what you want.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I don't require the trailing zero.

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I've also updated the question with a bit of problematic data that my program is reporting.  Thanks for your insights so far!

Comment: Are you in a position to upgrade to Python 2.7 (or later)?  That plus use of `round` would fix your issue (because the `json` library float encoder uses `repr` under the hood, and `repr` is better behaved in Python 2.7 than in earlier versions of Python).

Comment: @MarkDickinson, I can do that upgrade, and it looks like it fixes my problem.  Post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Builtin function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round) can help

```
In [16]: v=2.030000002

In [17]: json.dumps({'x': round(v, 3)})
Out[17]: '{"x": 2.03}'
```

Comment: The trailing zero is missing

Comment: @TimCastelijns `2.03` is the very same number as `2.030`

Comment: Yes, but OP might have different reasons requiring the extra 0. Can't imagine a 100k user could not find the `round()` function

Comment: But json would convert it to a float anyways, it would truncate it to 2.03

Comment: Much simpler than the other answers. It's working up to Python 3.9 (just tried). I would give it +2 if it were possible :-)

Answer (score 7):

Wrap the number into a `float`:

```
>>> s = float('%.3f' % (v))
>>> json.dumps({'x' : s})
{"x": 2.03}
```

Comment: Worked for me. The problem in my case was that the data was converted to numpy's `float64`  during processing. Explicitely casting `float` restored the original format

Answer (score 2):

This is something I found from from the [Python Standard library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

"Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> getcontext().prec = 6
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.142857')
>>> getcontext().prec = 28
>>> Decimal(1) / Decimal(7)
Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

"

A better import statement would be:

```
from decimal import getcontext, Decimal
```

Then you could apply those same functions to specify an arbitrary precision. Hope this helps! I haven't actually used this before.

For your case: (still has the trailing zero issue)

```
getcontext().prec = 3
s = '2.030'
var = float(Decimal(s))
```

`var` returns `2.03`

Answer (score 2):

This following approach seems promising:

```
import json

v = 2.030000002
result = []
for part in json.JSONEncoder().iterencode({'x': v}):
    try:
        tmp = round(float(part), 3)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        part = '{:.3f}'.format(tmp)
    result.append(part)
result = ''.join(result)

print result  # -> {"x": 2.030}
```