# formatting json.dump floats from dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have the following dictionary in Python:

```
dict_a = {"a": 3.55555, "b": 6.66666, "c": "foo"}
```

I would like to output it to a .json file with rounding up the floats up to 2 decimals:

```
with open('dict_a.txt', 'w') as json_file:
   json.dump(dict_a , json_file)
```

output:

```
{"a": 3.55, "b": 6.66, "c": "foo"}
```

Is that possible using ***python 3.8*** ?

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32145824/2280890) will likely help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,
Don't use var name `dict` as it's a safe word in python. use `dct` instead.

You can loop over your `keys, vals` and round them them to 2nd floating point. Full working example:

```
dct = {"a": 3.55555, "b": 6.66666}

for k, v in dct.items():
    if type(v) is float:
       dct[k] = round(v, 2)

with open('dict.txt', 'w') as json_file:
   json.dump(dict, json_file)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, I have updated the variable name of the dictionary and its contents. This does not work if the contents contain other data types.

Comment: Ok so you can add a little if statement, i will update the answer

Comment: I think it's a good solution, unless a JSON encoder was used. I tried checking that with a statement that checks if a string was there, but it did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this is by creating a new dictionary with the rounded values, you can do that in one line using dictionary comprehention while checking for non-float values as such:

```
Y = {k:(round(v,2) if isinstance(v,float) else v) for (k,v) in X.items()}
```

and then dump it. However a small note, do avoid using the word "dict" as your dictionary name, as its also a keyword in python (e.g. X = dict() is a method to create a new dictionary X). And its generally good practice to avoid those reserved keynames.

I do believe the above could could probably be optimised further (e.g, perhaps there is a function to either return the value for the round, or return a default value similar to the dictionary function get(), however I do not have any ideas on top of my mind.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, i updated the post to change the variable name and include a string in the dictionary. As this works using a comprehension for a dict with values as floats, it does not work if other data types are present.

Comment: All good. I can think of an improvement when I am home to allow comprehension to be used. Meanwhile, Erans answer should hopefully be sufficient